# Is devtools install_url broken?

Tags: r, devtools

When i do `devtools::install_uri` i get the following error:

```
Error: 'setInternet2' is defunct.
```

My R version is 3.5.1

I find it hard to believe that a mainstream package such as this one could be broken.

Comment: Could you do include the full code? `Error: 'install_uri' is not an exported object from 'namespace:devtools'` Did you mean `install_url`? BTW if it's defunct, maybe check the `News.md` file for info on what happened to it?

Comment: What version of `devtools` are you running? You can check with `sessionInfo()`. What OS version are you using?

Comment: This is how I can reproduce this error: `setInternet2()
Error: 'setInternet2' is defunct.
See help("Defunct")`. Perhaps this broke some function in the version you're using.

Comment: The devtools version is `2.0.2`. And its actually `install_url`